# How to create a popup when user clicks on any images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, shopify

I'm developing a website on Shopify. I need to know how to create a clickable image gallery. A popup with description and image appears when users click on any of the images in the gallery.

So far I'm done with the gallery, the only thing I need to know is how to make the gallery clickable with a pop up screen.

Here's the code for the gallery-data.js.liquid file:

```
        var gallery = [         
        {
          "img": "{{ 'Square_102.jpg' | file_img_url: "x270" }}",
            "text": "Gulvmontert",
        },
       {
          "img": "{{ 'Bille-_-Jo.png'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Bille og Jo",
        },{
          "img": "{{ 'Square_015.jpg'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Inspirasjon ",
        },{
          "img": "{{ 'Square_102.jpg'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Veggmontert",
        },{
          "img": "{{ 'Square_015.jpg'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Square",
        },{
          "img": "{{ 'Square_069.jpg'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Veggmontert",
        },{
          "img": "{{ 'Square_102.jpg'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Veggmontert",
        },{
          "img": "{{ 'Square_102.jpg'| file_img_url: "x270"}}",
            "text": "Veggmontert",
        },

    ];

     Here's the code for the gallery.js.liquid file: 

    function view(imgsrc) {
        viewwin = window.open(imgsrc, 'viewwin', 'width=600,height=300');
    }

    function RenderHtml() {
        var output = "";
        for (i = 0; i < gallery.length; ++i) {
            output += '<div class="gallery"><a target="_blank" rel="noopener 
            noreferrer">';
            output += ' <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">';
            output += '     <img src="' + gallery[i].img + '" 
         onclick="view("' + gallery[i].img + '")" alt="Forest" /';
            output += ' </a>';
          //  output += ' <div class="desc">' + gallery[i].text + '</div>';
            output += '</div>';
        }
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        RenderHtml();
    }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Try to get to any image and then set up a listener. You can get to them by accessing them like gallery[0].img.addEventListener ....

Comment: Have you actually attempted it? This is meant for help/debugging, not writing the whole thing for you.

Comment: There are many readily available jquery plugins for it. You can use anyone.

Comment: What plugin do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

For showing the Image and more Informations you can use modal from Bootstrap. With the event (click on image) you can get the Information which informations should be in the modal.

[W3School Modal Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)